# c# string to hex , hex to byte conversion

Tags: c#, byte, type-conversion

I have a method which takes a hex value and assign it as a plaintext but type of byte like that

```
byte plainText = 0xd7;
```

I want to take this value from textbox ,for exmaple the user will type  d7 to textbox and ı will assign it like

```
byte plaintText = 0xd7
```

I could not achive that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [`Convert.ToByte(String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx) method with the base set to 16 (hexadecimal):

```
String text = "d7";
byte value = Convert.ToByte(text, 16);
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
var myByte = Byte.Parse("d7", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to use this?

`Byte.parse`

Comment: yes ı tried     byte myByte = Byte.Parse(txtKey1.Text); gives error like input string is not correct format

Comment: @sebastian is the right answer as you have to supply the base.