# How to input comma separated Hex values into a textbox and output as hex values, c#

Tags: c#, textbox, hex, windows-forms-designer

Here is the code i've come up with so far for this but it throws this exception when I input a letter value such as AA.

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Also I would like to include some error message if the user inputs an invalid value. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
               private void GPIO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string hex = WriteValue.Text;
                    string[] hex1 = hex.Split(',');
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex1.Length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < hex1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex1[i]);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < hex1.Length; i++)
                    {
                    GPIO(h[index], dir, bytes[i]);
                    ReadValue.Text += bytes[i].ToString();
                    }
                 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it with base set to 16 (hexadecimal).

```
Convert.ToByte(text, 16)
```

Many duplicates:

[c# string to hex , hex to byte conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576296/c-sharp-string-to-hex-hex-to-byte-conversion)

[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Funny how easily it gets confusing when the answer is so simple. +1

Answer (score 1):

When you arrive at

```
bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex1[i]);
```

the value of `hex1[i]` is `"AA"`

Your app fails here because you cannot fit "AA" as a string in a single byte.

If you're looking for a byte array conversion of the string,
you will want to split that value into chars ; like this :

```
  string hex = "AA";
  string[] hex1 = hex.Split(',');
  List<byte[]> byteArrays = List<byte[]>();

  foreach (string t in hex1)
  {
        int byteIndex = 0;
        byte[] newArray = new byte[hex1.Length];
        foreach(char c in t)
        {
              newArray [byteIndex] = Convert.ToByte(c);
              byteIndex++;
        }
        byteArrays.add(newArray);
  }
```

But i don't think that's what you're after. you're looking to parse decimal values represented as a string.

Comment: ohhhh hang on. i didn't quite get what OP was trying to achieve.