# How to convert an hex to the 0x... byte format (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, hex, byte

I'd like to convert an `int` to `hex` string (**this part is OK**) and then convert the `hex` string to the `byte` format **`0x(theHexString)`** in order to use it into an array. For the moment I've got that code :

```
// Calculate the int that will be convert to Hex string
int totalLenght=11+request.Length;  
// Try to convert it into byte
byte totalLenghtByte=Convert.ToByte( totalLenght.ToString("X"));  
// put it into an array of bytes
xbeeFrame[2] =(totalLenghtByte);
```

For example, the int value is 18 and so the Hex string is 1D (Great !). But the problem is that I don't know if I've to do something else in order to get the 0x1D byte ...

Thank for your help !

Comment: `1D` is not `18`. its `29` because `D` is 13. also 18 would be `12`

Comment: Are you sure that is what you really need? `totalLenghtByte` is `byte` which is numeric datatype and you are trying to store string there.

Comment: Yes i think. I'm using this for creating an xbee frame. In xbee frame , 3rd byte is the lenght byte of the request . So i calculate the totalLenght with first line then convert it to hex ( lenght = 18  -> 1D ) and finally i'm trying to convert this hex string to a byte value ( hex : 1D -> byte : 0x1D )

Comment: Here is answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576296/c-sharp-string-to-hex-hex-to-byte-conversion

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes sory my mistake. It's because i add 11 to my lenght value (which was 18 in my example ) -> 11+18 = 29 -> 1D :)

Comment: @AlekseyNosik Huuuuuum sounds good ! Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try use the overload of `Convert.ToInt32` method that takes a numeric base from:

```
int int32Value = Convert.ToInt32("1D", fromBase: 16);

byte byteValue = Convert.ToByte(int32Value);
```

---

I'm not sure if understood the question.

If what you mean is you want to convert an Hexadecimal value to its C# representation ("0xVALUE") then just add that chars at the beginning of the resulting Hexadecimal string:

```
"1D".Insert(0, "0x");
```

Anyways, I made this function that will help you:

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies language style to represent an Hexadecimal value
/// </summary>
public enum HexadecimalStyle : int
{

    /// <summary>
    /// C# Hexadecimal syntax.
    /// </summary>
    CSharp = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Visual Basic.Net Hexadecimal syntax.
    /// </summary>
    VbNet = 1

}


/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Converts an Hexadecimal value to its corresponding representation in the specified language syntax.
/// </summary>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <example> This is a code example.
/// <code>
/// Dim value As String = HexadecimalConvert(HexadecimalStyle.CSharp, "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57")
/// Dim value As String = HexadecimalConvert(HexadecimalStyle.VbNet, "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57")
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <param name="style">
/// The <see cref="CryptoUtil.HexadecimalStyle"/> to represent the Hexadecimal value.
/// </param>
/// 
/// <param name="value">
/// The Hexadecimal value.
/// </param>
/// 
/// <param name="separator">
/// The string used to separate Hexadecimal sequences.
/// </param>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <returns>
/// The resulting value.
/// </returns>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <exception cref="InvalidEnumArgumentException">
/// style
/// </exception>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DebuggerStepThrough()]
public string HexadecimalConvert(HexadecimalStyle style, string value, string separator = "")
{

    string styleFormat = "";

    switch (style) {

        case CryptoUtil.HexadecimalStyle.CSharp:
            styleFormat = "0x{0}";

            break;
        case CryptoUtil.HexadecimalStyle.VbNet:
            styleFormat = "&H{0}";

            break;
        default:

            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(argumentName: "style", invalidValue: style, enumClass: typeof(HexadecimalStyle));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(separator)) {
        value = value.Replace(separator, "");
    }


    if ((value.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || (value.StartsWith("&H", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
        value = value.Substring(2);

    }

    return string.Format(styleFormat, Convert.ToString(value).ToUpper);

}
```

Comment: So if i just add 0x at the beginning of the string and then convert it to byte , i'll have :  (byte) 0xtheHexString   ? Should be what i need !

Comment: @Nethim No, a byte is a Byte type, a numeric datatype, not a String. It will neber have "0x". You need to convert it to string to append characters to the start of the string.

Comment: Ok but in my byte array, datas are defined like that : byte[] requestInByte={0x7E, 0x00 , 0x1D , ... }  That's why i don't understand how to have bytes whith 0x..  and not only  7E , 00, 1D ,...

Comment: 0xNumber is a literal C# numeric datatype, is not a string, you can't do what you want.

Comment: so simply using byte mybyte= 7E  or mybyte=0x7E is the same ?